# What caused Russia's currency to appreciate back to pre-war levels despite sanctions and debt default?

Tags: macroeconomics, foreign-exchange, default, sanctions, russia

Prior to its invasion of Ukraine on 24 Feb 2022, Russia's currency was trading at around 0.012 USD.

Today, the Ruble is back near pre-war levels (currently 0.12 USD):

[image]

I thought [war](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2022_Russian_invasion_of_Ukraine), [sanctions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_sanctions_during_the_Russo-Ukrainian_War), [tariffs](https://www.beehive.govt.nz/release/new-zealand-apply-trade-sanctions-response-russian-atrocities), and a [debt default](https://edition.cnn.com/2022/04/11/investing/russia-default-sp/index.html) would almost certainly cause a currency to depreciate significantly.

Why is the ruble so bouyant?